# JSP Tag to loop through objects

Tags: jsp

Im having a List of Objects that needs to be iterated in my JSP page,

The below code works fine and the code prints all the actor first name

```
<% ArrayList<Actor> acrs =  (ArrayList<Actor>)request.getAttribute("actorslist");
    for (Actor r:acrs){
        out.println(r.firstname + '\n');
    }
%>
```

but the same code using JSTL tag does not work fine..Here is my code...Im mixing both the JSTL and JSP language...but not sure how to get the acrs value using the JSTL tag...Any help pls?

```
<% ArrayList<Actor> acrs =  (ArrayList<Actor>)request.getAttribute("actorslist");%>
 <c:forEach var="Actor"  items="${acrs}">
    FirstName= Actor.firstname 
</c:forEach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `FirstName = ${ Actor.firstname }`. Otherwise `Actor.firstname` will be interpreted as standard string/html content.

```
<c:forEach var="Actor" items="${actorslist}">
    <p>${ Actor.firstname }</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
<c:forEach var="Actor"  items="${actorslist}">
FirstName= ${Actor.firstname} 
</c:forEach>
```